ZFS import unable to find any pools on RockyLinux after Reboot
I had a single ZFS pool comprised of 8 (6/2) drives in a ZFS pool and after my server was down for ~5 days of no power the zpool I had created no longer shows where I mounted it. When I first access the server I have to run sudo /sbin/modprobe zfs in order to run zfs list or zpool status.
$ zfs --version
zfs-2.0.7-1
zfs-kmod-2.0.7-1

$ uname -r
4.18.0-348.20.1.el8_5.x86_64

I try the following commands to attempt to import the zfs pool:
$ sudo zpool import -D -f tpool
cannot import 'tpool': no such pool available

$ sudo zpool import -a
no pools available to import

$ zfs list
no datasets available

I can run zdb and I get:
$ zdb
tpool:
    version: 5000
    name: 'tpool'
    state: 0
    txg: 7165299
    pool_guid: 11415603756597526308
    errata: 0
    hostname: 'cms-Rocky'
    com.delphix:has_per_vdev_zaps
    vdev_children: 1
    vdev_tree:
        type: 'root'
        id: 0
        guid: 11415603756597526308
        create_txg: 4
        children[0]:
            type: 'raidz'
            id: 0
            guid: 10941203445809909102
            nparity: 2
            metaslab_array: 138
            metaslab_shift: 34
            ashift: 12
            asize: 112004035510272
            is_log: 0
            create_txg: 4
            com.delphix:vdev_zap_top: 129
            children[0]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 0
                guid: 4510750026254274869
                path: '/dev/sdd1'
                devid: 'ata-WDC_WD140EDGZ-11B1PA0_9LK5RGEG-part1'
                phys_path: 'pci-0000:02:00.0-sas-phy2-lun-0'
                whole_disk: 1
                DTL: 11590
                create_txg: 4
                expansion_time: 1713624189
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 130
            children[1]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 1
                guid: 11803937638201902428
                path: '/dev/sdb1'
                devid: 'ata-WDC_WD140EDGZ-11B2DA2_3WKJ6Z8K-part1'
                phys_path: 'pci-0000:02:00.0-sas-phy0-lun-0'
                whole_disk: 1
                DTL: 11589
                create_txg: 4
                expansion_time: 1713624215
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 131
            children[2]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 2
                guid: 3334214933689119148
                path: '/dev/sdc1'
                devid: 'ata-WDC_WD140EFGX-68B0GN0_9LJYYK5G-part1'
                phys_path: 'pci-0000:02:00.0-sas-phy1-lun-0'
                whole_disk: 1
                DTL: 11588
                create_txg: 4
                expansion_time: 1713624411
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 132
            children[3]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 3
                guid: 1676946692400057901
                path: '/dev/sda1'
                devid: 'ata-WDC_WD140EDGZ-11B1PA0_9LJT82UG-part1'
                phys_path: 'pci-0000:02:00.0-sas-phy3-lun-0'
                whole_disk: 1
                DTL: 11587
                create_txg: 4
                expansion_time: 1713624185
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 133
            children[4]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 4
                guid: 8846690516261376704
                path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD140EDGZ-11B1PA0_9MJ336JT-part1'
                devid: 'ata-WDC_WD140EDGZ-11B1PA0_9MJ336JT-part1'
                phys_path: 'pci-0000:02:00.0-sas-phy4-lun-0'
                whole_disk: 1
                DTL: 386
                create_txg: 4
                expansion_time: 1713624378
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 384
            children[5]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 5
                guid: 6800729939507461166
                path: '/dev/disk/by-id/ata-WDC_WD140EDGZ-11B1PA0_9LK5RP5G-part1'
                devid: 'ata-WDC_WD140EDGZ-11B1PA0_9LK5RP5G-part1'
                phys_path: 'pci-0000:02:00.0-sas-phy5-lun-0'
                whole_disk: 1
                DTL: 388
                create_txg: 4
                expansion_time: 1713623930
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 385
            children[6]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 6
                guid: 3896010615790154775
                path: '/dev/sdg1'
                devid: 'ata-WDC_WD140EDGZ-11B2DA2_2PG07PYJ-part1'
                phys_path: 'pci-0000:02:00.0-sas-phy6-lun-0'
                whole_disk: 1
                DTL: 11585
                create_txg: 4
                expansion_time: 1713624627
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 136
            children[7]:
                type: 'disk'
                id: 7
                guid: 10254148652571546436
                path: '/dev/sdh1'
                devid: 'ata-WDC_WD140EDGZ-11B2DA2_2CJ292BJ-part1'
                phys_path: 'pci-0000:02:00.0-sas-phy7-lun-0'
                whole_disk: 1
                DTL: 11584
                create_txg: 4
                expansion_time: 1713624261
                com.delphix:vdev_zap_leaf: 137
    features_for_read:
        com.delphix:hole_birth
        com.delphix:embedded_data

So I know the drives are still there and the pool is still formed (I also see it in the Avago utilities when I boot the server all drives are present). However lsblk only returns my main SSD running the server.
So I am unsure of what to do or how to get my zpool back after the power outage. Any ideas on what I can do/run next or what else I can do to troubleshoot this?
Also why do I have to keep running $ sudo /sbin/modprobe zfs after every reboot?
UPDATE
$ sudo blkid
[sudo] password for chrs987:
/dev/sda1: UUID="bfa9805a-ea03-4618-ad4b-dffaa4e24474" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="fa0465e1-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="wox6DN-0oFz-vQNy-bxLe-4VG8-qUfB-mek3fc" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="fa0465e1-02"
/dev/mapper/cl-root: UUID="b80d8c8d-2288-46b9-b0b5-376ac194aabd" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="xfs"
/dev/mapper/cl-swap: UUID="6c348d6d-d7bd-4c78-8aee-b683f9264dc4" TYPE="swap"
/dev/mapper/cl-home: UUID="734c6bfc-afd5-4523-9818-43786aef06aa" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="xfs"

$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xfa0465e1

Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048   2099199   2097152     1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       2099200 488396799 486297600 231.9G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/cl-root: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/cl-swap: 19.7 GiB, 21151875072 bytes, 41312256 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/cl-home: 162.2 GiB, 174143307776 bytes, 340123648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

$ lsscsi
[0:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      CT250MX500SSD1   023   /dev/sda

$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 5500 I/O Hub to ESI Port (rev 13)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 13)
00:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 13)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 7 (rev 13)
00:09.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 9 (rev 13)
00:0a.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub PCI Express Root Port 10 (rev 13)
00:14.0 PIC: Intel Corporation 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub System Management Registers (rev 13)
00:14.1 PIC: Intel Corporation 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub GPIO and Scratch Pad Registers (rev 13)
00:14.2 PIC: Intel Corporation 7500/5520/5500/X58 I/O Hub Control Status and RAS Registers (rev 13)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 90)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JIR (ICH10R) LPC Interface Controller
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) 4 port SATA IDE Controller #1
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) 2 port SATA IDE Controller #2
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme II BCM5716 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 20)
01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme II BCM5716 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 20)
02:00.0 Serial Attached SCSI controller: Broadcom / LSI SAS2008 PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS-2 [Falcon] (rev 03)
03:00.0 SATA controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1061/ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)
06:03.0 VGA compatible controller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. MGA G200eW WPCM450 (rev 0a)
fe:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
fe:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
fe:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
fe:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
fe:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Mirror Port Link 0 (rev 02)
fe:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Mirror Port Link 1 (rev 02)
fe:02.4 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series QPI Link 1 (rev 02)
fe:02.5 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series QPI Physical 1 (rev 02)
fe:03.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Registers (rev 02)
fe:03.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Target Address Decoder (rev 02)
fe:03.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller RAS Registers (rev 02)
fe:03.4 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Test Registers (rev 02)
fe:04.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Control (rev 02)
fe:04.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Address (rev 02)
fe:04.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Rank (rev 02)
fe:04.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Thermal Control (rev 02)
fe:05.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Control (rev 02)
fe:05.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Address (rev 02)
fe:05.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Rank (rev 02)
fe:05.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Thermal Control (rev 02)
fe:06.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Control (rev 02)
fe:06.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Address (rev 02)
fe:06.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Rank (rev 02)
fe:06.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Thermal Control (rev 02)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Mirror Port Link 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Mirror Port Link 1 (rev 02)
ff:02.4 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series QPI Link 1 (rev 02)
ff:02.5 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series QPI Physical 1 (rev 02)
ff:03.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Registers (rev 02)
ff:03.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Target Address Decoder (rev 02)
ff:03.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller RAS Registers (rev 02)
ff:03.4 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Test Registers (rev 02)
ff:04.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Control (rev 02)
ff:04.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Address (rev 02)
ff:04.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Rank (rev 02)
ff:04.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Thermal Control (rev 02)
ff:05.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Control (rev 02)
ff:05.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Address (rev 02)
ff:05.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Rank (rev 02)
ff:05.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Thermal Control (rev 02)
ff:06.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Control (rev 02)
ff:06.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Address (rev 02)
ff:06.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Rank (rev 02)
ff:06.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon 5600 Series Integrated Memory Controller Channel 2 Thermal Control (rev 02)

$ lspci -nn | grep LSI
02:00.0 Serial Attached SCSI controller [0107]: Broadcom / LSI SAS2008 PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS-2 [Falcon] [1000:0072] (rev 03)

Also already have the mpt3sas kmod package installed for my raid controller.
Package kmod-mpt3sas-43.100.00.00-2.el8_10.elrepo.x86_64 is already installed.


Please post blkid and fdisk -l output

@ewwhite added.

Thanks. Maybe lsscsi?

I don't think the driver or kernel module related to your storage controller is loaded. The block devices aren't present, based on the fdisk -l output.
Can you try manually loading the avago controller driver module?

How would I go about loading the avago controller? Would it be an issue with my H200 SAS/SATA controller?

Anything related to your controller in lshw or dmesg?

Nothing that I can see that stands out @eKKiM

@Jav_Py This might be relevant: https://forums.rockylinux.org/t/rocky-broadcom-sas-compatibility/11653 although that is for Rocky 9. (Yeah, I got bit when I upgraded a system to RHEL 9 a year or two ago...) What RAID HBA do you have?  Can you add the output from lspci to your question?

@AndrewHenle I have added the output of lspci along with the output of lspci -nn | grep LSI showing the version of my raid controller. Ive seen the compatibility issues with these controllers and I have installed kmod-mpt3sas-43.100.00.00-2.el8_10.elrepo.x86_64.

@Jav_Py Fusion-MPT SAS-2? That looks like the driver should be mpt2sas and not mpt3sas.

@AndrewHenle are you sure it should be mpt2sas? I ran the command lspci -nn | grep LSI and based on what is shown here (https://elrepo.org/wiki/doku.php?id=deviceids) it shows mpt3sas for device ID 1000:0072?
